# jquery, firefox: event preventDefault does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following code in my view in MVC:

```
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @model IEnumerable<GeoGame.Models.ConsiderResponse>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Show Second Day Comments";
    }
    <h2>
        Show Second Day Comments</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("StoreThirdDayComments", "DiscussionForum", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <p>
            <a href="#" id="instrReminder">Instructions</a>
        </p>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    User
                </th>
                <th width="85%">
                    Comments
                </th>
                <th>
                    My reaction
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr class="choice">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.memberNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.justification)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Agree")<font style="background-color: green"
                            color="black"> Agree </font>
                        <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Disagree")<font style="background-color: red"
                            color="black"> Disagree </font>
                        <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Opinion_" + item.ID, "Neither")<font style="background-color: yellow"
                            color="black"> Neutral </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <br />        
            <label>
            Please respond to <b>each</b> of your peers' comments using the following pattern:</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <text><i>I agree/disagree/am neutral with 1's comments because: (insert comments)</i></text>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
            <textarea rows="7" cols="75" id="ThirdDayComments" name="ThirdDayComments"></textarea>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit and answer question -->" />
        </p>
    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
                var isValid = true;
                if ($.trim($("#ThirdDayComments").val()) == '') {                
                    isValid = false;
                }
                if ($('tr.choice').not(':has(:radio:checked)').length) {                
                    isValid = false;
                }
                if (isValid == false) {
                    alert('Please choose agree, disagree, neutral for each comment and explain the reasons in the textbox provided');
                }
                if (isValid == false) {
                    e.returnValue = false;
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
            $('#instrReminder').click(function (e) {
                alert("1. Read the comments made by your peers.\n2. Select agree/disagree/neutral for each of them.\n3. Fill out the text box according to the pattern mentioned.\n4. Click submit.\n5. You will be taken to a page with a question with multiple-choice answers.\n");
                e.returnValue = false;
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });             
    </script>
```

I want to prevent the page from proceeding when the radio buttons are not chosen or the text box is not filled. This works in Chrome.
However, in Firefox, if the user clicks on submit a couple of times without choosing the radio buttons or filling up the text box, an alert pop ups with a message (as in code), but also "Prevent additional popups". When that option is selected and when I hit submit again, the page does *not* prevent default anymore. It just goes through. I do *not* want that.
I checked a lot of other posts, but they didn't seem to solve this problem exactly.
Any ideas on how to fix this in Firefox? I'm using version 36.0.1.

Comment: FYI, `e.returnValue = false;` is unnecessary. jQuery does that for you when you call `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the two `isValid == false` conditions together, and put `preventDefault` before the `alert`. Try this:

```
if (isValid == false) {
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Please choose agree, disagree, neutral for each comment and explain the reasons in the textbox provided');
}
```

The same needs to be done in the click handler for the `#instrReminder` element.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning errors after several alerts are blocked by firefox.
Solution is to NOT alert more than once or not alert at all and a MUCH better choice of event handlers is the form submit instead of the submitbutton click.

Like this - assuming the ID of the form is DiscussionForum

```
 $('#DiscussionForum').on("submit",function (e) {
   var isValid = true;
   $("#message").empty();
   if ($.trim($("#ThirdDayComments").val()) == '') {                
     isValid = false;
   }
   if ($('tr.choice').not(':has(:radio:checked)').length) {                
     isValid = false;
   }
   if (!isValid) {
     e.returnValue = false;
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#message").html('Please choose agree, disagree, neutral for each comment and explain the reasons in the textbox provided');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've told Firefox that you don't want the page to produce any more alerts, the calls to `alert()` result in an exception being thrown.

Two ways to deal with this:

1. Wrap your calls to `alert()` in a `try catch`:

   ```
   try {
     alert("whatever");
   }
   catch (err) {
     console.log("denied");
   }
   ```

   Now the exception will be handled.
2. Stop using `alert()`, as it's ugly and causes problems like the one you're facing now.